# Vundle not authenticating github

Tags: authentication, vim, github, vundle

I have this on my `~/.vimrc`.

```
set nocompatible              " be iMproved, required
filetype off                  " required

set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
call vundle#begin()
Plugin 'gmarik/Vundle.vim'
Plugin 'crooloose/nerdtree.git'
Plugin 'tomasr/molokai'
Plugin 'kien/ctrlp'
Plugin 'bling/vim-airline'
syntax enable
colorscheme molokai
```

Pretty, straight forward really. I have couple of plugins that I want to install using Vundle but whenever I do `:PluginInstall` it prompts me for the github username and password. I know that my username and password are correct but it keeps failing to authenticate. I have two way authentication on in github btw. I don't think that matters.
However, I get the following error.

```
[2014-09-19 23:18:14] 
[2014-09-19 23:18:14] Plugin crooloose/nerdtree.git
[2014-09-19 23:18:14] $ git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/crooloose/nerdtree.git' '/home/shriek/.vim/bundle/nerdtree'
[2014-09-19 23:18:14] > Cloning into '/home/shriek/.vim/bundle/nerdtree'...
[2014-09-19 23:18:14] > remote: Invalid username or password.
[2014-09-19 23:18:14] > fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/crooloose/nerdtree.git/'
[2014-09-19 23:18:14] > 
[2014-09-19 23:19:51] 
[2014-09-19 23:19:51] Plugin kien/ctrlp
[2014-09-19 23:19:51] $ git clone --recursive 'https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.git' '/home/shriek/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'
[2014-09-19 23:19:51] > Cloning into '/home/shriek/.vim/bundle/ctrlp'...
[2014-09-19 23:19:51] > remote: Invalid username or password.
[2014-09-19 23:19:51] > fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.git/'
[2014-09-19 23:19:51] > 
[2014-09-19 23:19:52] 
[2014-09-19 23:19:52] Helptags:
[2014-09-19 23:19:52] :helptags /home/shriek/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/doc
[2014-09-19 23:19:52] :helptags /home/shriek/.vim/bundle/vim-airline/doc
[2014-09-19 23:19:52] Helptags: 2 plugins processed
```

I even tried connecting to github by doing `ssh -T git@github.com` which says 
`Hi shriek! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`

So, I'm kinda lost on what's going on. Help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe this is a simple error in the url declared in your plugins (that you are trying to clone)

https://github.com/crooloose/nerdtree.git does not exist.
https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree.git does.

Similarly:

https://github.com/kien/ctrlp does not exist.
https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim does

By declaring the right username and repo names in your `~/.vimrc`, you should avoid those errors when cloning said plugins.

Comment: Wow. You're absolutely right. These typos are almost too embarrassing.